# Hibernate Map<Entity, Embeddable> always delete and then insert on session.merge

Tags: java, hibernate

Our physical data model looks like the following

```
USER
user_id (...other attributes)

ORGANIZATION
organization_id (...other attributes)

USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES
user_id org_id email
```

We have the following Hibernate mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private Map<OrganizationEntity, UserOrgAttributes> userOrgAttributes;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION")
public class OrganizationEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private int organizationId;
}

@Embeddable
public class UserOrgAttributes {

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email= email;
    }
}
```

We use Embeddable to map USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES because we want to add more columns later on.

At the DAO layer, we create a Transient UserEntity object (not currently managed by Hibernate), then call session.merge(userEntity). We turned on show_sql in the Hibernate properties, and what we notice is that it always deletes all records on USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES where user_id = the ID value of the userEntity, then insert the user_id, organization_id, email values for a new row. We would ideally like this to be an "update" rather than "delete/insert".

Furthermore, it inserts fewer rows than expected. Suppose we have the following data

```
USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES
user_id org_id email
1       2      abc@xyz.com
1       3      (null)
```

The Transient userEntity to be persisted has 2 entries in the userOrgAttributes map, one where the key is an OrganizationEntity with organizationId = 2, the value an instance of UserOrgAttribute with email = 'abc@xyz.com'. The second entry has a key with organizationId = 3 and value with email = null.

When Hibernate merges this entity, it deletes both rows, but then only inserts one, the row where the email is null (organizationId = 3).

Now suppose we have

```
USER_ORG_ATTRIBUTES
user_id org_id email
1       3      (null)
```

Persisting the same userEntity with 2 entries in the map, we get a delete followed by 2 inserts!

Obviously we would expect 2 inserts or 2 updates each time. This is Hibernate 4.2 if that helps.